# What can I replace oversized waterproof outlet cover with?

Tags: receptacle

In my house I have two external outlets like this:

[image]

[image]

Both of them cracked and need replacement. Though I found a straight replacement ([Leviton 4986-GY 1-Gang Duplex Device Wallplate Cover, Oversize, Weather-Resistant, Thermoplastic, Device Mount, Horizontal, Gray](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000U3I4F0)) based on reviews they will crack soon again.

I tried to find alternatives but there are no clear candidates. Ideally I'd like to install something like [weatherproof deep in-use cover](https://www.homedepot.com/p/TAYMAC-1-Gang-Horizontal-or-Vertical-Weatherproof-Deep-In-Use-Cover-MM510C/300306936) one but they don't cover underlying round box. What are my options?

[image]

**Update.** Followed the answer, worked like a charm! Need to paint around outlet.

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Easy. Just get a [round to single gang adapter like this](https://amzn.to/3cRppJ9):

[image: round to single gang adapter]

Amazon even suggests this is bought together with an in-use cover and GFCI, so you are clearly not the only one with this problem.

If you don't have GFCI on this circuit, you should add it. Even with an in-use cover, that would be better done inside (breaker panel or an earlier receptacle in the circuit).

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense! Yes, both external outlets are protected by GFCI (inside a house). And one trips it every time it rains (expectedly) =)

Comment: @ZakiMa Consider replacing that receptacle with a weather-resistant one. http://wiringdevicesupport.eaton.com/GFCI/70709712/What-is-the-difference-between-a-weather-resistant-GFCI-and-a-standard-GFCI.htm

Comment: Curious as to why the GFCI should be done inside? Is this for convenience, so that you don't need to go outside to reset?

Comment: @LShaver GFCI is a sensitive piece of electronics, particularly now that they have automatic self testing. Water, temperature changes etc lead to faster failure.

Comment: Thanks. Do they make cold-weather rated GFCI outlets? I just installed one -- wondering if I should instead swap out the breaker. It's the only load on the circuit.

Comment: I don't know as far as cold specifically. But there are "weather resistant" gfci.

Comment: Replaced both with a recommended round-to-single-gang-adapter. @MonkeyZeus, thank you for suggestion, replaced receptacles with a weather-resistant ones.